# When UITextView is scrolling ...?

Tags: ios, swift3, textview

I have a textView which is not editable so my textView is only readable. And there is a ImageView on the top of textView. I want that, when the textView is scrolling, ImageView (Y position) disappear slowly depends on How many the textView scrolled.. If I should give an example, it looks like Twitter "Me" page but non blurred. I hope I was clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of call UIScrollViewDelegate, make your viewcontroller delegate to self.Because it's subclass of UIScrollview.

and implement scrollView function according to your need.Suppose you want to disappear image after scrolling finished. then implement this method.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"Finished scrolling");
}
```

Comment: I tried already it before :/ But it didn't work :/ Still thank you :)

Comment: Did you set delegate?

Comment: Yes I had done and I used scrollViewDidScroll instead of yours. It worked. Thank you!